# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

hey guys i update kotlin version after that i git this problem, anyone face that too

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:v1.8.20.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/v1.8.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-v1.8.20.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/v1.8.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-v1.8.20.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: i got it by using this way

Using legacy plugin application:



buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20")
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"